# Update UIButton title after receiving reply from SKProductsRequest for showing in-app purchases price

Tags: ios, uibutton, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to create two buttons whose label is initially set as a default value. The two buttons are managed by a popOverViewController, in which the viewDidLoad method initialise all the controls. I also have another method called addButtons that gets executed by the AppDelegate after receiving a valid response from Apple's servers containing products descriptions and prices.

My problem is that I can't get the label updated with that method.

My viewDidLoad method in the popOverViewController is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
// Add a label to the popover's view controller.
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(button1Week:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
NSString *priceWeekly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"weekly subscription"];
[button setTitle:priceWeekly forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 50.0);
[button2 addTarget:self
            action:@selector(button1Month:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 setTitle:@"monthly subscription" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 55.0, 200.0, 50.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
}
```

and my update label method, of which I'm sure it gets called at the right time, is:

```
-(void)addButtons {
[self.button setTitle:@"updated label" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button2 setTitle:@"updated label 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

can you please check my code and suggest the right way to update the labels? Basically I want to initialize the controls with a default label because of the waiting time between controls creation and server response.

UPDATE:

I have updated the code as follows, but still everything that's inside the addButtons method gets executed as I have an NSLog to check, but the button title still remains as created in viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
// Add a label to the popover's view controller.
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
ilManifestoAppDelegate *delegate = (ilManifestoAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(button1Week:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//    [button setTitle:priceWeekly forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 50.0);
[button2 addTarget:self
            action:@selector(button1Month:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
//    [button2 setTitle:@"monthly subscription" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 55.0, 200.0, 50.0);
//    [self addButtons];
NSString *weekPrice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"settimanale a %@",delegate.priceWeek];
[button setTitle:weekPrice forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setTitle:@"updated label 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSLog(@"week price %@", weekPrice);
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
}

-(void)addButtons {
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
[button setTitle:@"modificato" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
NSLog(@"addButtons executed");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, the code is being called?? Place a breakpoint and run the project. See if addButtons is called.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Are you sure addButtons is being called. Have you put a log in the method to check?

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I've placed the breakpoint and everything is fine

Comment: when you get the product descriptions from the apple servers, check if you are getting them correctly. Put NSLogs in the delegate methods

Comment: I have NSLogs everywhere, and data is properly received and then formatted. I'm able to output the strings. Things are that the button titles seem to get created and label assigned only in the viewdidload method, and everything happening later is not accepted

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` you are using `button` and `button2`. In `addButtons` you are using `self.button` and `self.button2`. Did you ensure that these are the same buttons?

Also place a breakpoint in `addButtons` to see if it really is called, if you haven't done this yet.

Have you also created the outlet to the buttons in the xib, if you haven't placed them only with code.

Comment: I have placed a breakpoint and I'm sure that the method is being called. Also I'm sure that the buttons are the same, I've also tried changing to: [button setTitle:@"updated label" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: the buttons are created only in code, no XIB for the popOverViewController

Comment: I have solved my issue by implementing the easy EBPurchase in-app purchases class into my code. Thanks all.

https://github.com/ebutterfly/EBPurchase